# How to curve_fit a function that return dataFrame on a data set

Tags: python, pandas, curve-fitting

I am trying to curve fit my defined function to a dataset. I defined my function using pandas and it prints the values. But when I try to optimize it using Curve_fit, it gives me an error that "list index out of range". I don't understand why?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ydata=np.array([1.2,1.21,1.2,1.19,1.21,1.22,1.8,2.47,2.49,2.49,2.5])
xdata = np.linspace(0,1,num=11).round(2)

def halfTrapz(x, m, a, tau1, tau2):
    y = np.zeros(len(x))
    dfy = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(x,y)),columns=['x','y'])
    ta1=dfy.index[dfy['x']==tau1].tolist()
    ta2=dfy.index[dfy['x']==tau2].tolist()
    # ta1=list(np.array(ta1)+1)
    # ta2=list(np.array(ta2)+1)   #In order to consider ta2 in [:ta2]
    dfy.iloc[:ta1[0],1] = a
    b = a - m*dfy.iloc[ta1[0],0] 
    dfy.iloc[ta1[0]:ta2[0],1] =  m * dfy.iloc[ta1[0]:ta2[0],0] + b 
    dfy.iloc[ta2[0]:,1] = m * dfy.iloc[ta2[0],0] + b
    return dfy['y']
    
z=(halfTrapz(xdata, 5,1.2,0.5,0.7))
plt.plot(xdata,z,'g--')
plt.plot(xdata,ydata)
```

#First section (above) works fine for some given value and it can plot the function. However. second part when I try to use curve_fit this function. It gives me error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0BWN.png)

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
   
popt, pcov = curve_fit(halfTrapz, xdata, ydata)
print(popt)
print(pcov)

plt.plot(xdata, func(xdata, *popt), 'r-')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message "list index out of range" means exactly what it says: you are trying to access a list element that doesn't exist. In this case it's caused because `ta1` can be an empty list, and you are trying to access the 0th element here `dfy.iloc[:ta1[0],1] = a`

Now why would `ta1` be empty? The offending statement is this one `dfy['x']==tau1`. You are filtering based on a comparison here, but `tau1` can be a `float`, hence you are going to have headaches with float comparison. e.g `1.0==1.0000001` evaluates to `False`.

I don't pretend to understand the math here, but if you *really* want to filter on a float field I suggest using something like `np.isclose`.

Comment: Thank you it was very helpful, the problem as you said was for "1.0==1.0000001". Don't know why it generates 1.0000001 but I solve it by rounding the numbers to 2 decimals

Comment: @tulips No probs, please mark the answer as accepted so people can see you don't need more answers